# vb.net how can boaderless form restore when task ivon click taskbar click

Tags: vb.net, forms, taskbar, minimize

i want border less form for my application.

i am set Form Border Style as none.

how can that form minimize and restore when taskbar tab click.

i am add  following code to windows form project

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = ""
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    End Sub
```

then i want it minimize and restore by clicking taskbar tag
how i do it

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code and a note letting us know your exact error/problem. If you haven't tried anything, or have no code to post, this is not the correct place for you to gain help.

Comment: i am add  follwing code to windows form project

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = ""
        Me.ControlBox = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    End Sub


then i want it minimize and restore by clicking taskbar tag
how i do it